# Resharper vs. Coderush - 2010 remake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper, coderush

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216/resharper-vs-coderush) for discussions on previous versions.

Asking the question again since Visual Studio 2010 has been officially released. Does anyone have any visibility this early on as to which is better? What about any other products that may be out there? This one will probably be on my dime, so I'd like the wisdom of those with experience before pulling the trigger on a decision.

Comment: +1: Good question. // Viewers should be mindful of the fact that respondents will be naturally biased towards the tool that they are most comfortable with. Nevertheless, opinions can be useful.

Comment: Absolutely agree. This is the primary reason why I game a list of things to consider with my answer :)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216/resharper-vs-coderush

Comment: @Ruben - Please re-read the post. I've made it clear this is not a repost, but another phase of the same question because of tool version changes. Your referenced post is over a year and a half old rendering it obsolete for the latest version of Visual Studio as well as the tools in question themselves.

Comment: @Boydski: This is by no means a serious dup, and you referred to the prior question which is great. I dont expect it to be closed. I also upvoted it. I stiff dont think the world is a better place for having two editions of the question or Rory's answer though (great and all as it is). I disagree that much as changed in the world of CR and R# in the last 18 months. Their relative positions are pretty much the same. The CR answers already refer to the CR test runner, which has only just been released. And the functionality is the same on VS2010 v vs2008

Comment: @Ruben - Your comments are exactly what I've been looking to receive with this new question. The old one being old, I don't trust that it would've gotten the visibility necessary to answer my question in a timely manner. Thank you sir!

Comment: Hey, happy to help :D Seriously though, there's been far more traffic on the other question. I suggest this is an ideal case for a bounty.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IMHO I prefer CodeRush

The VS2010 version is out now ... Very stable,very performant.

*Update: CodeRush also appears to be cheaper. R#r commercial license appears to be $349 where as CodeRush is $249 dropping to $99 on renewal*

All that said, this is a very personal decision. It will depend very much on what you are after.

The following is a link to another answer I gave regarding **things to consider when making the decision** between tools like this.

[Comparing developer productivity tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593929/comparing-developer-productivity-tools/2599560#2599560)

Comment: Supposedly, the "competitor" in this video comparison I saw just this morning is Resharper. The IDE sure looks like VS 2010. Maybe it was beta or RC? http://bit.ly/cCHhao

Comment: The IDE was VS2010. I think the CodeRush version being demoed in this was one of the RC's, but I am not certain... For that you'd need to ask Mark Miller.

Answer (score 3):

The only news right now on the CR front is the short term news that Code Rush Xpress for VS2010 is released whereas the full thing is not as yet.

In addition to Rory's very complete CR-flavoured review, I thought the one of the most important contributions to the other thread was [this one from DX's Mark Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216/resharper-vs-coderush/1930393#1930393) which is pretty measured (We can trust that any factual inaccuracies will result in a swarm of comments from competitor evangilists.)

But I'm voting to close this as its not a new question and doesnt have new answers (Sorry Rory!)

Comment: I respectfully disagree with your final statement. Please see my comment above.

Comment: I think this is a valid question, but I completely concede Ruben's right to vote to close it.

I would suggest that the statement about voting to close is fine, but is more appropriate as a comment on the question, than as part of an answer.

Comment: @Rory Becker: In general agree with VTC being a comment/vote thing (which I also did). But then I disagree with cut and pasting a big answer. And fragmenting a discussion by asking the saem question again.

Comment: Ok I think you have a valid point about the Cut & paste... I will adjust appropriately and add a link instead :)

Comment: @Rory Becker: +1 atcha! Personally I'd love to know whats happened in R# land in the last 18 months. Looking forward to the test runner getting even more polish (extra UI tricks I've been logging suggestions for that suit my usage - I'm pretty confident that as-is, it'll make lots of people happy already).

Comment: If you're going to vote to close a question, you shouldn't answer it as well.

Answer (score -2):

Another vote for CodeRush. Things in CodeRush that are better than R# are: powerful template/plugin engine, more cofigurable, less resource killer.